# Communicating multiple times w/ subprocess (multiple calls to stdout)

Tags: python, stream, subprocess, pipe

There's a similar question to mine on [this thread][1].

I want to send a command to my subprocess, interpret the response, then send another command.  It would seem a shame to have to start a new subprocess to accomplish this, particularly if  subprocess2 must perform many of the same tasks as subprocess1 (e.g. ssh, open mysql).

I tried the following:

```
subprocess1.stdin.write([my commands])
subprocess1.stdin.flush()
subprocess1.stout.read()
```

But without a definite parameter for bytes to `read()`, the program gets stuck executing that instruction, and I can't supply an argument for `read()` because I can't guess how many bytes are available in the stream.

I'm running WinXP, Py2.7.1

### EDIT

Credit goes to @regularfry for giving me the best solution for my real intention (read the comments in his response, as they pertain to accomplishing my goal through an SSH tunnel).  (His/her answer has been voted up.)  For the benefit of any viewer who hereafter comes for an answer to the title question, however, I've accepted @Mike Penningtion's answer.

Comment: Have you considered using [Pexpect](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pexpect/)?

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but I'll look into it right now.  (If you'd like to leave the suggestion as an answer to the question, it might be just the answer I'm looking for.)

Comment: Looks like a no-go for me.  I'm on Windows.

Comment: I guess I'll need `wexpect` instead of `pexpect`.  But I can't find the elusive `wexpect` for download.  Any hint where to look?

Comment: http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JellicleCat, I'm following up on the comments.  I believe wexpect is a part of [sage](http://sagemath.org/)... AFAIK, it is not packaged separately, but you can download [wexpect here](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/goreckc/sage/wexpect/).

Honestly, if you're going to drive programmatic ssh sessions, use [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/).  It is supported as an independent installation, has good packaging, and should install natively on windows.

### EDIT

Sample paramiko script to cd to a directory, execute an `ls` and exit... capturing all results...

```
import sys
sys.stderr = open('/dev/null')       # Silence silly warnings from paramiko
import paramiko as pm
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
import os

class AllowAllKeys(pm.MissingHostKeyPolicy):
    def missing_host_key(self, client, hostname, key):
        return

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
USER = ''
PASSWORD = ''

client = pm.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/known_hosts'))
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AllowAllKeys())
client.connect(HOST, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)

channel = client.invoke_shell()
stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('rb')

stdin.write('''
cd tmp
ls
exit
''')
print stdout.read()

stdout.close()
stdin.close()
client.close()
```

Comment: Request further instruction: I've installed paramiko, but I'm having no success connecting as yet.  I create an SSHClient object, then call connect, supplying the login info that I would for a normal `ssh` command, but I get the following: `gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`.  I wonder if gaining access via a public key is necessary, but my server at work doesn't have a `.ssh` directory set up so I don't know of any place to put my public key.

Comment: @JellicleCat, have you tried using the script to login to `localhost`?  It is hard to say what the error could be from without seeing some code

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are:

1. Use a line-oriented protocol (and use readline() rather than read()), and ensure that every possible line sent is a valid message;
2. Use read(1) and a parser to tell you when you've read a full message; or
3. Pickle message objects into the stream from the subprocess, then unpickle them in the parent. This handles the message length problem for you.

Comment: I'm expecting MySQL responses over ssh, so I don't see how the first two choices can save me (responses tend to run several lines long and have no delimiter of which I know).  Could you offer some insight on Pickling from a stream?  I presume I need to write a python script on the remote side of the ssh to perform the pickling, and my local script will de-pickle?

Comment: Oh, I see. I had assumed that both processes were Python. If you want to see what pickle does, look here: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#example

Comment: Also, is there something you're trying to do that the python database adapters can't do? It seems a little unusual to be calling the command-line client directly.

Comment: Thanks for asking.  The purpose of my app is to access the MySQL database at work, make some queries, write the results to a local file.  I can't just have Python do a remote MySQL connection because the server restricts MySQL access to the server IP.  IT tells me that the only way I may access it, then, is to SSH tunnel in.

Comment: Look into SSH port forwarding. You can set up an encrypted proxy for the MySQL connection with a single ssh command, which will mean you can avoid having to parse mysql command-line output. It's the Right Way to do what you're attempting, I think, because you can use the existing python MySQL bindings. There are instructions for putty (if that's what you're using) here: http://www.cs.uu.nl/technical/services/ssh/putty/puttyfw.html

Comment: Thanks.  I've no idea what to do once I've set up a tunnel to port X on my machine, though.  Is there a python doc on executing my python commands over a given port?  (I'm really in the dark.)

Comment: Basically, once the port forward is started, you can pretend that the database is running on your machine. It's not recent, but http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html should still be good. Just set the host to "localhost" and the port to whatever the local side of the port forward is, and you should be away.

Comment: Thank you for your patient assistance.  I've followed your instructions to the best of my understanding, but my python console freezes when I try to connect.  I've edited my question up top to give more details about my process.  Would you have a look at them and let me know if you have any idea what I've done amiss?

Comment: That looks good, I *think* - can you use the mysql command-line client to connect via putty with those settings?

Answer (score 1):

This approach will work (I've done this) but will take some time and it uses Unix-specific calls.  You'll have to abandon the subprocess module and roll your own equivalent based on fork/exec and os.pipe().

Use the fcntl.fcntl function to place the stdin/stdout file descriptors (read and write) for your child process into non-blocking mode (O_NONBLOCK option constant) after creating them with os.pipe().

Use the select.select function to poll or wait for availability on your file descriptors.  To avoid deadlocks you will need to use select() to ensure that writes will not block, just like reads.  Even still, you must account for OSError exceptions when you read and write, and retry when you get EAGAIN errors.  (Even when using select before read/write, EAGAIN can occur in non-blocking mode; this is a common kernel bug that has proven difficult to fix.)

If you are willing to implement on the Twisted framework, they have supposedly solved this problem for you; all you have to do is write a Process subclass.  But I haven't tried that myself yet.